# unset field that is indexed makes : E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: mongoose, null, duplicates, unset

I have table "users" with index "phone"
When i try to unset a field that is indexed, first time it's correctly unsetted, and this query return the users that now haven't field "phone"

```
db.getCollection('users').find({"phone":null})
```

but when i try to unset annother user's field phone t i receive this error :

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: fflok.users index: phone_1 dup key: { : null }
```

please help

this is the query of unset field

```
User.updateOne({ _id: userId }, {$unset: {phone: 1 }}, callback);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this code in schema :

```
 phone: {type: String, trim: true, index: true, unique: true, sparse: true},
```

and on database i selected sparse on the index :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code . It will help you .

```
User.update(
   { _id: userId },
   { $unset: { phone: ""} }
)
```

Comment: what the actual scenario is ? Once you unset the field cannot be set again or you not able  use to use unset multiple time  ? @user2285831